# C# Unity "A Field Initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method...."

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm brand new to unity and I'm following this [tutorial here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/2d-character-controllers?playlist=17093), and I figured out the `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>`part but I still get the `A Field Initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property. UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()`

I don't understand how to fix it and no where else has helped. I posted on the Unity forums and have yet to receive an answer.

Here's the code. Thanks for any help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControllerSCRIPT : MonoBehaviour {

public float maxSpeed = 10f;
bool faceRight = true;
Animator anim;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    //...
}   

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate ()
{

    float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

    if (move < 0 && !faceRight)
        Flip();
    else if (move < 0 && faceRight)
        Flip();

}

void Flip()
{

    faceRight = !faceRight;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;

}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure this is the code with the error? There is nothing wrong with the code in the question....

Comment: I have no other scripts yet, so it has to be this. I think it's mad at the rigidbody2D but I dont know why because I followed the tutorial as best I could.

Comment: Idk what happened but it just now decided to work. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Ok. I don't see how this question will be useful in the future. You can delete it if you want

Comment: Field Initialiser can only use static variables, the results of static methods and/or constants. However the inspecific nature of the error message (it can not even tell what you try to assign) indicates that there is some tripup in the parsing itself. Such things can happen ocassionally.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
private Rigidbody2D body;

void Start
{
 body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

in FixedUpdate () use following,

```
body.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, body.velocity.y);
```